# Regex correction

Tags: java, regex

I'm using this regular expression to parse a string like `"CALENDAR YEAR: 2012"`.Can someone suggest a better one ? And I want to use matcher.find()  `(CALENDAR YEAR:\\s+)?((2\\d\\d\\d))`

I want to get 2012 in a group.

I can't understand why it prints null when i do this:

```
 while (myMatcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(myMatcher.group(1));
     System.out.println(myMatcher.group(2));

    }



CALENDAR YEAR: 
2012
null
null
```

EDIT: How will I change the expression if the code is using matches and i Still want to parse the year out of the string?

Comment: on what delimiter you want to format your string ??

Comment: So, dates prior to 2000 don't exist? What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: "Improvement" usually means tightening the expression so that it captures more of what you want and less of what you don't want, which means having a detailed understanding of the data requirements, which means that you need to provide more description and examples of what you need to match.

Answer (score 0):

**READ A REGEXP MANUAL**.

Obviously, you have no idea when to use the `?` character, and when not. Or when to use `()`...

You can just leave it away.

```
CALENDAR YEAR:\s+(\d{4})
```

should do the trick already. But you just threw random characters into your regexp, instead of looking at the various examples around.

Comment: Actually, even with this it goes into an infinite loop printing 2012 with matcher.matches()

Comment: Because you apparently don't understand what `matcher.matches()` does. It is not an iterator. It is meant to give the same result again.

Comment: And yes, `matcher.find()` has a different behaviour from `matcher.matches()`. It is the better choice if you expect more than one match in the string. Otherwise, you can use both, but for `matches` you need to read the manual for the difference between matching a whole string and finding a substring.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use extra group(s) at all - go with regex pattern

```
(?<=CALENDAR YEAR: )2\\d{3}(?!\\d)
```

...and result will be in

```
myMatcher.group(0)
```